# Python - MySQL SSL Connections

Tags: python, mysql, windows, ssl

I have a MySQL Server set up to use SSL and I also have the CA Certificate.

When I connect to the server using MySQL Workbench, I do not need the certificate. I can also connect to the server using Python and MySQLdb on a Mac without the CA-certificate.

But when I try to connect using the exact same setup of Python and MySQLdb on a windows machine, I get access denied. It appears that I need the CA. And when I enter the CA, I get the following error

`_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (2026, 'SSL connection error')`

My code to open the connection is below:

```
db = MySQLdb.connect(host="host.name",    
                 port=3306,
                 user="user",         
                 passwd="secret_password",  
                 db="database", 
                 ssl={'ca': '/path/to/ca/cert'})
```

Could anyone point out what the problem is on a windows?

Answer (score 5):

I just got the following to work with Python 2.7 and MySQLdb (1.2.4):

```
database = MySQLdb.connect(host='hostname', user='username', db='db_name',
    passwd='PASSWORD', ssl={'ca': '/path/to/ca-file'})
```

This is what you had so there must be something else going on here. I wonder if you have something either incorrect with the your local CA file or possibly the cert on the server? Can you get a copy of the CA file from the server?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
import ssl
from databases import Database
sslctx = ssl.create_default_context(ssl.Purpose.SERVER_AUTH, 
    cafile='ca.pem')
sslctx.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_REQUIRED
sslctx.check_hostname = True
sslctx.load_cert_chain(certfile='client.crt', keyfile='pkey.key')

database = Database(DATABASE_URL, ssl=sslctx)
```

`databases` library provides support for PostgreSQL, MySQL, and SQLite.
Also useful for async frameworks.

Answer (score 0):

Im using pymysql and I had some problems to connect using SSL keys and certs: for the "ssl" attribute I set up as a dictionary inside. Try as below:

```
db = MySQLdb.connect(host="host.name",
    port=3306,
    user="user",
    passwd="secret_password",
    db="database",
    ssl={'ssl':
            {'ca': '/path/to/ca/ca',
             'key': '/path/to/ca/key',
             'cert': '/path/to/ca/cert'
            }
         }
)
```

Comment: Are you sure this isn't moving the options out of the way so that it stops using SSL?

Comment: @Andy Indeed, although it "solves" the error it disabled TLS entirely.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a bit old but I found a way to get this to work. Use pymysql instead of MySQLdb and write the connection as:

```
import pymysql

conn = pymysql.connect(user = 'user', password = 'passwd'
, database = 'db', host = 'hst', ssl = {'ssl' : {'ca': 'pathtosll/something.pem'}})
```

The point people miss (including myself) is that ssl needs to be a dictionary containing 
 a key 'ssl' which has another dictionary as a value with a key 'ca'. This should work for you.

Comment: I don't know what's the reason for this nested `ssl` dictionary, and even can't find in `pymysql` code why this should work. I just use one (not nested) dictionary as follows: `pymysql.connect(..., ssl={'ca': 'ca.pem'})` and it works.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pymysql

conn = pymysql.connect(host= # your host, usually localhost,
user = # your username,
passwd = # your password,
db = #your database name ,
ssl ={'ssl': r'path of your pem file'})
```

Comment: Please add some description alongside with your code.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old but according to the documentation [MYSQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-connectargs.html) on object and its properties. What i tested on Python 3.8 this is the format I used

```
        Cnxn=  mysql.connector.connect(
        host="ip_address",
        user="usern",
        password='pass',
        database="database",
        port="port",
        ssl_ca=Path("/path/to/cert/ca.crt")
        
    )
```

As Side note I had to run this openssl on PEM file first as well and convert to a .crt file

```
openssl x509 -in ./Downloads/ca.pem -out ./Downloads/ca.crt -outform PEM
```